# appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config returns "Authentication Failed" without even prompting me for authentication

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a Java appengine app with remote_api installed as per http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/10/using-the-bulkloader-with-java-app-engine/

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>RemoteApi</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RemoteApi</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When I go to myapp.appspot.com/remote_api with a web browser, I see the message "This request did not contain a necessary header," which I understand is expected.

But when I run `appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --url=http://APPID.appspot.com/remote_api --application=APPID --filename=config.yml` from my command line (with the proper APPID) I get

```
C:\ag\dev>appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --url=https://correctid.appspot.c
om/remote_api --application=correctid --filename=config.yml
Creating bulkloader configuration.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20101114.081901
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20101114.081901.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20101114.081901.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to correctid.appspot.com/remote_api
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed

C:\ag\dev>
```

I've already tried the no_cookies option, which didn't help.  I also tried using `-e correctadminmail@gmail.com`.  Neither of these changed my output at all.

How can I specify my authentication parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen if your app is configured to use OpenID for logins - OpenID isn't compatible with remote_api.

This blog post describes the problem and a solution:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication

The solution is in Python though - you might be able to do something equivalent in Java (or upload some Python code to a different version of your app, just for the remote api).

Comment: My app was configured to use OpenID, but I don't actually use it, so I just switched away from it and voila!  Thanks.

Comment: I am using Python, am not using OpenID, and am still getting this error. I also tried not using "login: admin" (per the blog). Any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind - my app was configured with a Google Apps ID, which also does not work.